# How to save as a Stata .dta file from a web link

Tags: stata

Using Windows Explorer.

Download a CSV from the same web directory. Works fine (Save the Target as... then save it on my local Windows 10 PC).

Along side the csv file at the target location, there is a .dta file which is Stata file. Converting to other formats, like CSV, is not option. Has to download it. So went through the Save the Target. Got a jungle massy pile of data on Windows Explorer. How to tame the beast to save it down, as it is as .dta file?

Comment: Try `use` in Stata with the path and file name. Expecting browsers to understand `.dta` file formats is optimistic.  We can't see the file in question to experiment ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `copy` [command](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/dcopy.pdf) to download files from a url:

```
copy http://www.stata.com/examples/simple.dta simple.dta
```

Comment: Thanks. I used to read.dta to read it directly off the web link. Copy is interesting.